# Assigning NSTimeInterval to Marker

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I was wondering if it's possible to assign a NSTimeInterval to a particular marker. So that when that marker is selected it will set a notification with that unique time interval.

My Marker Definition:

```
GMSMarker *marker1 = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker1.title =   @"Title";
marker1.snippet = @"Snippet";
//marker.opacity = 0.0;
marker1.map = mapView;
```

My Notification Definition:

```
-(void) buttonTapped:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"you clicked on button %ld", (long)sender.tag);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM,dd,yyyy,hh:mm"];

    NSString *fireDateString = @"08,12,2016,09:30";

    NSDate *fireDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:fireDateString]; // The     schedule date time.
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotification.alertBody = @"alertText";
    localNotification.alertAction = @"buttonTitle";
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;


    // Schedule it with the app
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

I'm trying to set the fireDate = currentDate + TimeInterval, where the TimeInterval is tied to the particular marker.

Comment: Where in your code TimeInterval?

Answer (score 0):

Create subclass of `GMSMarker` and add timeInterval property.

MyGMSMarker.h

```
@interface MyGMSMarker: GMSMarker
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval timeInterval;
@end
```

MyGMSMarker.m

```
@implementation Product

- (id)markerWithPosition:position {
    if (self = [super markerWithPosition:position]) {
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And usage:

```
MyGMSMarker *marker1 = [MyGMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker1.title =   @"Title";
marker1.snippet = @"Snippet";
marker1.map = mapView;  
marker1.timeInterval = 60;
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of that?

Comment: I added example to the answer.